# imagick::coalesceImages not working right with animated image

Tags: imagick

I try example resize animated image in php.net http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.coalesceimages.php

```
$image = new Imagick($file_src); 

$image = $image->coalesceImages(); 

foreach ($image as $frame) { 
  $frame->cropImage($crop_w, $crop_h, $crop_x, $crop_y); 
  $frame->thumbnailImage($size_w, $size_h); 
  $frame->setImagePage($size_w, $size_h, 0, 0); 
}
```

but it not work. When I try to show index of frame, for example:

```
$image = new Imagick($file_src); 

$image = $image->coalesceImages(); 

foreach ($image as $frame) { 
  echo 'aa-';
  $frame->cropImage($crop_w, $crop_h, $crop_x, $crop_y); 
  $frame->thumbnailImage($size_w, $size_h); 
  $frame->setImagePage($size_w, $size_h, 0, 0); 
}
```

it onli show
aa-
mean only oneframe
And when I remove line

```
$image = $image->coalesceImages();
```

it work correctly. 2 frame detected. 
So is it a bug or I was wrong in somewhere?

That my phpinfo()

```
System           Linux 2.6.18-402.el5 x86_64 
PHP Version      5.5.22
imagick version  3.1.2
```

and my image using test[image]

Comment: Your code works for me...or at least it does when I set the missing variables. Please see http://sscce.org/ for a guide on how to write better reproduction code. It could be a bug in the version of ImageMagick you are using.

Comment: Yes, I reinstall my ImageMagick and that work.